# VueJS: registering component and access it from plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm writing a plugin allowing user to select certificate of Digital Signature. Certificates comes from another plugin.
I got CertificateDialogComponent, code of it as follows:

```
<template>
    <el-dialog
            ref="dialog"
            title="Choose Certificate"
            :visible.sync="show"
            append-to-body
            :before-close="hideDialog"
            width="40%">
        <el-table
                ref="table"
                :data="certificates"
                stripe
                style="width: 100%">
            <el-table-column
                    prop="subject"
                    label="Subject">
            </el-table-column>
            <el-table-column
                    prop="thumb"
                    label="Thumb">
            </el-table-column>
        </el-table>
        <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
            <el-button @click="hideDialog">Cancel</el-button>
        </span>
    </el-dialog>
</template>
<script>
  import {Dialog, Table, TableColumn, Button} from 'element-ui'
  export default {
    name: 'certificate-dialog',
    components: {
      [Dialog.name]: Dialog,
      [Table.name]: Table,
      [TableColumn.name]: TableColumn,
      [Button.name]: Button
    },
    data () {
      return {
        show: false,
        certificates: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      selectCertificate (certs) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.certificates = certs
          this.show = true
          this.$refs.table.$on('row-click', (row) => {
            this.show = false
            resolve(row)
          })
          this.$refs.dialog.$on('close', () => {
            reject(new Error('Closed By User'))
          })
          this.$on('close', () => {
            reject(new Error('Closed By User'))
          })
        })
      },
      hideDialog () {
        this.show = false
        this.$emit('close')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When user clicks on row, this component emit event 'selected' with selected certificate. 
It is easy to import this component in every other component where I need it, but I need it too often. I want to make global method getCertificate, which can open this dialog, without registering it every time, and can access this component internal method selectCertificate.

Sorry if I didn't explained well, English is not my native language, feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: You want to add that `selectCertificate` to every component, is that it?

Comment: Yes. So now I'm trying to register this component in App.vue and use provide and it's kind of works

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to do this, but not in the way I wanted.
I created methods I needed in CertificateDialog component, added this component to App component, created a reference to that methods and used provide option:

```
<template>
  <certificate-dialog ref="certificateDialog"/>
</template>
<script>
  methods: {
    getCertificate () {
      return this.$refs.certificateDialog.getCertificate()
    },
    signData () {
      return this.$refs.certificateDialog.signData()
    }
  }
  provide () {
    getCertificate: this.getCertificate,
    signData: this.signData
  }
</script>
```

And now I can use this methods in every component I want. It simple, uses the Vue capabilities, but not as "mobile" and redistributable as plugin could be. But this works and works well, so